# Dose Web Application Context and Servlet Application Context is same thing?

Tags: spring

Dose Web Application Context and Servlet Application Context is same thing?
I think these are same but different name.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you speak about `Servlet Context` and not `spring-servlet`:

They are different things.
Every Java web applications that use Servlet technology will have a `servlet context`, doesn't related to Spring.
Servlet-context started when a Servlet application is deployed. Servlet Context holds all the configurations.

On the other hand, `ApplicationContext` is a Spring tech; i.e., it's a container to hold Spring beans.

So, for your questions, those are different.

BTW, `spring-servlet` it's a single front servlet handles all the HTTP requests of a particular web application. This front servlet has all the controls over incoming requests.

Comment: Thank you for answer :)
When I search on google someone said servlet context is only one is web application but the other person said servlet context is same count as servlet....
Which is right?

Comment: ApplicationContext  and Servlet Context are not the same